# xslt replace value based on a match from an imported nodeset

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm attempting to import a node set and then search the input stream and do a replace on a match of a value.

I believe its sufficient to say that incoming xml looks like:

```
<someElement name="replaceMe" id="1">
<someElement name="replaceMeToo" id="2">
```

and imported node (myNodeSet) set would look like:

```
<parentOfMatch name="replaceWithThisValue">
    <matchName>replaceMe</matchName>
</parentOfMatch>
<parentOfMatch name="replaceWithThisValueToo">
    <matchName>replaceMeToo</matchName>
</parentOfMatch>
```

the outcome I want is:

```
<someElement name="replaceWithThisValue" id="1">
<someElement name="replaceWithThisValueToo" id="2">
```

my feeble attempt:

```
<xsl:variable name="root" select="/"/>
<xsl:variable name="myNodeSet" select="collection('file:/C:/temp/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes')"/>

<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="someElement/@name">
    <xsl:for-each select=".=$myNodeSet/parentOfMatchName/matchName">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <!-- but here I can't select the parent of the context node. 
             how can I change the for-each -->
        <!-- select ro make parentOfMatchName node the context but 
             compare with the matchName node? -->
            <xsl:value-of select="../@name"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

again, I'm attempting to locate all someElement/@name nodes in the incoming node set with $myNodeSet/parentOfMatchName/matchName and replace someElement/@name with $myNodeSet/parentOfMatchName/@name.

thanks a bunch.

Comment: What does your input XML look like? What does `$myNodeSet` look like?

Comment: have updated the question with inputs and desired outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a `for-each` for this. This is all you need:

```
<xsl:template match="someElement/@name">
    <xsl:variable name="replacement"
                  select="$myNodeSet/parentOfMatch[matchName = current()]/@name" />
    <xsl:attribute name="name">
        <xsl:value-of select="$replacement | (.)[not($replacement)]"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```